# Sending my current object to another class

Tags: java

Sorry if the wording of the title isn't correct. Say I have a class and I have initialized an object of that class, now in the constructor for that class I want to pass that new object's values to another class, is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
public class testinger
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        prep ab = new prep(10);
    }
}


class prep
{
    private int a;
    prep(int x)
    {
        a = x;
        complete tim = new complete(/*how to send my current prep object there?*/);
    }

    public int getA()
    {
        return a;
    }
}
class complete
{
    complete(prep in)
    {
        in.getA();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the current instance using the **this** keyword.

```
prep(int x)
{
    a = x;
    complete tim = new complete(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the the keyword `complete tim = new complete(this);`

For example in Java **`this`** is a keyword. **It can be used inside the Method or constructor of  Class. It(this) works as a reference to the current Object whose Method or constructor is being invoked**. T**he this keyword can be used to refer to any member of the current object from within an instance Method or a constructor**

read more details [here](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/this-keyword-in-java/)